# Is there a workaround for Gmail Throttling for a Large IMAP migration

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap

I'm trying to move a former Outlook user to Gmail (not Google apps). I'm using a tool that does this via IMAP; however, I've run into issues with Google times out and stops accepting data. Is there a workaround to somehow get Gmail to sip in a large volume of messages?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Thunderbird, I've found that I only get throttled when trying to copy the entire [Gmail] superfolder. All the other folders worked fine. I got around this by selecting chunks of 25,000 messages for each of the folders in [Gmail] and copying them. Took a while, but worked.